# Travelling Moscow - Beijing in Winter then backpacking the way down to Indonesia - Packing Advice

Tags: russia, backpacking, asia, trans-siberian

I will be travelling on board the Trans Siberian Railway throughout February, understandably, i'll need warm clothes & snow boots. Once I arrive to Beijing, I plan on using trains and buses to make my way to Indonesia. Along this journey, I cant imagine I would need boots and coats, rather t shirts, shorts & trainers.

Does anyone have any advice? Ideally I'll only be taking a 55L rucksack. Would the best thing to be pack everything and mail all my cold weather gear back to an address in the UK?

Comment: It's a tough problem.  Things like big boots are incredibly big and ungainly to handle once you arrive in a hot climate.  And some sort of shipping option would not be cheap  :/

Comment: This might sound off the wall, but is leaving behind / gifting / selling your heaviest gear an option? I appreciate it might not be feasible if you’ve got new-ish, top of the range equipment!

Comment: I believe shipping snow boots and other (bulky) winter gear from China to UK will cost a small fortune. Maybe buy some used cheap stuff you can abandon without a problem?

Comment: You might also be able to find advice on our sister site [outdoors.se].

Comment: How many kg do you think we’re talking? Approximate replacement value, assuming you’ll use the stuff again?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than bringing single purpose winter gear consider equipping yourself with multi-purpose gear:

Rather than snow boots bring a good set of hiking boots instead. For me those work well enough in both winter and warmer conditions. (But then I don't like carrying my backpack  and hiking on flipflops.)

**Layer up**: rather than a thick winter coat get a (gore-tex or similar) hard shell. That doubles as a raincoat and windbreaker in many other conditions, on mountain treks, ferry crossings etc. Combine that hard-shell with a mid layer such as a soft-shell or down jacket (which compress and travel really well) that are individually also quite versatile.

A merino wool T-shirt is good thermal base layer in colder conditions and something you can wear on it's own even in the tropics.

etc.

Comment: Multipurpose gear could be an option, but the OP is traveling across Siberia (where -40°C at night is possible, and no humidity) to Indonesia (where +33*C during the day is possible, and there is high humidity).  That range of temps   and humidity is extreme.  I've lived in Siberia during a winter and just my coat would challenge a 55L pack - let alone my hat, scarf and thick gloves.